# Performing multiple calculations on a Python Pandas group from CSV data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have daily csv's that are automatically created for work that average about 1000 rows and exactly 630 columns.  I've been trying to work with pandas to create a summary report that I can write to a new txt.file each day.

The problem that I'm facing is that I don't know how to group the data by 'provider', while also performing my own calculations based on the unique values within that group.

After 'Start', the rest of the columns(-2000 to 300000) are profit/loss data based on time(milliseconds).  The file is usually between 700-1000 lines and I usually don't use any data past column heading '20000' (not shown).

I am trying to make an output text file that will summarize the csv file by 'provider'(there are usually 5-15 unique providers per file and they are different each day).  The calculations I would like to perform are:

```
Provider = df.group('providers')
total tickets = sum of 'filled' (filled column: 1=filled, 0=reject)
share % = a providers total tickets / sum of all filled tickets in file
fill rate = sum of filled / (sum of filled + sum of rejected)
Size = Sum of 'fill_size'
1s Loss = (count how many times column '1000' < $0) / total_tickets
1s Avg = average of column '1000'
10s Loss = (count how many times MIN of range ('1000':'10000') < $0) / total_tickets
10s Avg = average of range ('1000':'10000')
```

Ideally, my output file will have these headings transposed across the top and the 5-15 unique providers underneath

While I still don't understand the proper format to write all of these custom calculations, my biggest hurdle is referencing one of my calculations in the new dataframe (ie. total_tickets) and applying it to the next calculation (ie. 1s loss)

I'm looking for someone to tell me the best way to perform these calculations and maybe provide an example of at least 2 or 3 of my metrics.  I think that if I have the proper format, I'll be able to run with the rest of this project.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want is [DataFrame.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), with more examples in the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Usage is fairly straightforward.

You have a field called `'provider'` in your dataframe, so to create groups, you simple call `grouped = df.groupby('provider')`. Note that this does no calculations, just tells `pandas` how to find groups.

To apply functions to this object, you can do a few things:

1. If it's an existing function (like sum), tell the grouped object which columns you want and then call `.sum()`, e.g., `grouped['filled'].sum()` will give the sum of `'filled'` for each group. If you want the sum of *every* column, `grouped.sum()` will do that. For your second example, you could divide this resulting series by `df['filled'].sum()` to get your percentages.
2. If you want to pass a custom function, you can call `grouped.apply(func)` to apply that function to each group.

To store your values (e.g., for total tickets), you can just assign them to a variable, to `total_tickets = df['filled'].sum()`, and `tickets_by_provider = grouped['filled'].sum()`. You can then use these in other calculations.

**Update**:
For one second loss (and for the other losses), you need two things:

1. The number of times for each provider df['1000'] < 0
2. The total number of records for each provider

These both fit within groupby.

For the first, you can use `grouped.apply` with a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions). It could look like this:

```
_1s_loss_freq = grouped.apply(lambda x: x['fill'][x['1000'] < 0].sum())
```

For group totals, you just need to pick a column and get counts. This is done with the `count()` function.

```
records_per_group = grouped['1000'].count()
```

Then, because `pandas` aligns on indices, you can get your percentages with `_1s_loss_freq / records_per_group`.

This analogizes to the 10s Loss question.

The last question about the average over a range of columns relies on pandas understanding of how it should apply functions. If you take a dataframe and call `dataframe.mean()`, pandas returns the mean of each column. There's a default argument in `mean()` that is `axis=0`. If you change that to `axis=1`, pandas will instead take the mean of each row.

For your last question, 10s Avg, I'm assuming you've aggregated to the provider level already, so that each provider has one row. I'll do that with `sum()` below but any aggregation will do. Assuming the columns you want the mean over are stored in a list called `cols`, you want:

```
one_rec_per_provider = grouped[cols].sum()
provider_means_over_cols = one_rec_per_provider.mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I was able to complete some, however, I'm stuck on 1s toxicity, 10s toxicity and 10s avg.  I haven't really been able to figure out the .appy(func). Also, how can I group all these into a dataframe, rather than having them print separately each time with provider.  I added what I completed so far

Comment: Sure Tom, I updated the answer above (not sure if you get a notification about that)

Comment: Thanks James, I created the file and it all looks good.  Only other question is for the 1 and 10 second loss, how can I add an if statement to those.  I need to make sure that the function is looking at the 'filled' column and only counting the losing trades that were actually filled and not the rejected ones too.  (ie. filled=1, reject=0).

Comment: Edited above. `x['1000'] < 0` creates a boolean index, so you can use that to grab only the values of x['fill'] where that's true. The line edited above is `_1s_loss_freq = grouped.apply(lambda x: x['fill'][x['1000'] < 0].sum())`